# How do I display only the first and second most recent post separately without using a loop in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to display separately the first and second most recent posts from a category without using a loop. Below is what I've tried; the item1 div should display the most recent and the item2 div should display the second most recent.

```
  <div class = 'item item1'>
  <?php get_posts('numberposts=1&offset=1&category='); ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
  <?php endwhile;?>
    </div>

   <div class = 'item item2'>
  <?php get_posts('numberposts=2&offset=1&category='); ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
  <?php endwhile;?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why not `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 2`, put it to an array and use the first and second index?

Comment: I need the div names to remain the same for the slider is there a way to have the code in <?php get_posts('numberposts=1&offset=1&category='); ?> to display only the second most recent post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in function for this called: `wp_get_recent_posts()`

With the following params:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'numberposts' => 10,
    'offset' => 0,
    'category' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'include' => ,
    'exclude' => ,
    'meta_key' => ,
    'meta_value' =>,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'draft, publish, future, pending, private',
    'suppress_filters' => true );

    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );
?>
```

Example:

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '2' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<div><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" ><h3>' .   $recent["post_title"].'</h3></a></div>';
    }
?>
```

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) to retrieve two posts and put them in an array to use wherever you like.